# CSS - why does my sidebar drops to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css

I spent almost an hour searching why my sidebar here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/

Is dropping to the bottom of the page.

Could you please advise on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#leftcontent` div is not closed out with a closing `</div>` tag after your loop.

Edit your index.php, find [the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), and look for the end of the loop (usually it looks like `endwhile; endif;`. Add a closing `</div>` tag immediately after that (but outside of the `<?php ... ?>` tags).

Comment: +1 for the pesky closing div tag...gets me every time when I move too fast.

Comment: Actually, wait... I think I was wrong. The problem is in one of your posts... the one titled "Machine Learning Ex5.1 – Regularized Linear Regression". There's a beginning `<div>` tag in the post content there, that's not closed out. That seems to be why the rest of the page is unbalanced.